# How to re-arrange and group data from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 4 columns: Date, Shift, Good-Parts, Bad-parts...
Not all dates have all 3 shifts worth of data.
what I want to do is re-arrange the data so that each date is a single row with good and bad part qty's for each recorded shift displayed to the right.

```
change this:  
Date, 1st, Good, Bad  
Date, 2nd, Good, Bad  
Date, 3rd, Good, Bad  
Date, 1st, Good, Bad  
Date, 1st, Good, Bad  
Date, 1st, Good, Bad  
Date, 2nd, Good, Bad


to this:  
      1st Shift  2nd Shift  3rd Shift  
Date, Good, Bad, Good, Bad, Good, Bad  
Date, Good, Bad,  
Date,                       Good, Bad  
Date, Good, Bad, Good, Bad
```

how do I create a Macro that can scan down the 2nd column and move the 2 data cells for each 2nd and 3rd shift record up to the appropriate date row in the appropriate shift columns...

[image: Example-sheet]

Comment: I think you need to change that `vb.net` tag to `vba`. It appears you're doing this through the excel macro language (vba)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: Hmm... looks like a simple pivot-table

Comment: I didn't realize a Pivot table could do that... hopefully it is just that simple...    researching now

Answer (score 0):

@DirkReichel is right, this is a pretty simple PivotTable.

Here is some mock data I made
[image: Mock Data]

After selecting that data and clicking `Insert > PivotTable`, I moved the headers like this - **columns**: shift, **rows**: day, **values**: good, bad.
[image]
(Excel included the 'sum of values" bit into the **columns** list on its own)

And here was the result
[image]